# Removing the mean in finding PSD

Tags: signal-analysis, power-spectral-density

Does removing the mean value of the signal effect the estimation of power spectral density(PSD)? If it effects, how?

What is the advantage we can get by removing the mean of the signal in estimating the PSD ?

Can the advantage be in dealing with the signal points whose magnitude is very large and we can not see the changes(also frequency content) in the signal since the changes are very small comparing the magnitude of signal points?

Comment: i think it does not affect